# How to unlock Lyndons final quest in D3 RoS

Tags: diablo-iii

I've done the event where we find Lyndon's brother, now, having the dagger I need to seek Rea.

Lyndon's quote was that we would deal with it after it's all over, meaning defeating the final boss, but after that he has no new quotes and adventure mode removes the quotes at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: The next expansion, coming soon™.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to keep talking with him, since now the expansion is out.